# how to put home screen in android apps

Tags: java, android

I created android application using android studio. I want set home screen when I launch that application. I'm using navigation drawer layout. I got only blank white screen while launch application.

I designed home screen if I put in activity_main.xml means navigation process not working. Where do I put.

Please anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u be more specific or more elaborate, this info is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

The home screen should be defined in your AndroidManifest.xml

Just add :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

To the `<activity>` of your choice

Answer (score 0):

1.Start Class Used for a Splash Screen
2.main Activity Class For Default home page

add like this in your manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: MainActivity is java file..But i created home page in xml file

Answer (score 0):

You should put the homescreen or MainActivity At AndroidMenifest.xml :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```